# psutil python package version 5.9.5 not able to install with python3.11.4

Tags: failed-installation, psutil, python-3.11

trying to upgrade psutil package to latest version 5.9.5 not able to install with python3.11.4

tried installing psutil latest package with python3.11.4 and lower version of psutil getting below error

```
          running install_scripts
  psutil could not be installed from sources. Perhaps Python header files are not installed. Try running:
    sudo yum install gcc python3-devel
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6wug4m80/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 229, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6wug4m80/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6wug4m80/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 497, in <module>
      main()
    File "setup.py", line 462, in main
      setup(**kwargs)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6wug4m80/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 163, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6wug4m80/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6wug4m80/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6wug4m80/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6wug4m80/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 328, in run
      impl_tag, abi_tag, plat_tag = self.get_tag()
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "setup.py", line 379, in get_tag
      python, abi, plat = bdist_wheel.get_tag(self)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6wug4m80/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 278, in get_tag
      assert tag in supported_tags, "would build wheel with unsupported tag {}".format(tag)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  AssertionError: would build wheel with unsupported tag ('cp311', 'cp311', 'linux_x86_64')
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for psutil
Failed to build psutil
ERROR: Could not build wheels for psutil, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects